# Visual studio plugin To Choose Project to load

Tags: visual-studio-2010

there was a plugin for vs2010 that allowed to choose in a solution what project to load when the solution was opened, and what projects to keep unloaded. Anyone know how is named?

Comment: <curious>What are you requirement to do such a thing?</curious>

Comment: Nevermind i found it, is called "solutionloadmanager" Steve u can check here http://code.google.com/p/solutionloadmanager/

Answer (score 1):

Was it Ankhsvn? http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/